# Target all <td> of a row with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am a beginner in jQuery, and stuck on something. I hope someone will help me out.

I want to change the color of the value in all `<td>` from a specific `<tr>`. The `<tr>` is Days left. I want to make all the `<td>` values in that specific `<tr>` to be red if the value is < 0 , and make it green if the value is > 0 . I have tried a lot and can only get the first TD to become green.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td').text().trim() > "0") {
      $('#tt').css('color', 'green');
    } else {
      $('#tt').css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataex-res-configuration">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-class="expand">Days Left</th>
      <th data-hide="phone">Book Title</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Card No:</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Card Owner</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Quantity Rented</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Rented Date</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Due Date</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry didn't read properly :D edited for jquery

you can use first-child selector

```
jQuery( "#main td:first-child" ).css('','');
```

[first-child selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#main td:first-child').each(function(){
        if(parseInt($(this).text()) < 0){
            $(this).css('color','red');
        }else{
            $(this).css('color','green');  
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataex-res-configuration">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-class="expand">Days Left</th>
      <th data-hide="phone">Book Title</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Card No:</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Card Owner</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Quantity Rented</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Rented Date</th>
      <th data-hide="tablet,phone">Due Date</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">-1</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="tt">121344534</td>
      <td>the Great Gatsby</td>
      <td>34ABDSFS3332</td>
      <td>James Carter</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12-4-2018</td>
      <td>13-4-2019</td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRentBookModel">
          <i class="la la-edit"></i>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewRentBookModel">
            <i class="la la-eye"></i>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModel">
              <i class="la la-
                        la-trash"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

-- Modified Snippet --

Comment: Thanks alot ralph that worked but only 1 problem, It doesnt work for else if, below is the code: `$(document).ready(function(){
        $('tr').each(function(){
          if($(this).find('td').text().trim() > "0"){
              
              $("#main td:first-child").css('color','green');
          }

          else if ($(this).find('td').text().trim() <= "0") {
                
                $("#main td:first-child").css('color','red');
          }
         
        });
    });`

Comment: @BabarAli I created a codepen for you to check if this is what you need

Comment: @BabarAli modified answer